# How to prove that $U=\{f\in X^G: f(e)=b_k\}$ is open in $X^G=\{f\,\,|\,\,f:G\to X\}.$

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a Boolean group of the cardinality $\mathfrak{c}=2^\mathbb{N}$ and $X=\{a\}∪\{b_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ a convergent sequence
with the limit point $a$. If $e$ is the neutral element of $G$ and $h:G\to X$, then $h(e) = b_k$, for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

How to prove that $U=\{f\in X^G: f(e)=b_k\}$ is open in $X^G=\{f\,\,|\,\,f:G\to X\}.$

Thanks for you help!

Comment: open under which topology?

Comment: hello @Paul Sinclar...is under Product topology or pointwise Topology.

Comment: Why do you say $h(e) = b_k$ for some $k$? If $h$ is an arbitrary map $G \to X$, then there is no reason $h(e)$ cannot be $a$ instead of one of the $b_k$.